# Is this butterfly bush dead?

Tags: shrubs

[image][image: butterfly bush]

Should I prune this bush or is it not going to grow back ?

Comment: Are there any growing buds? Its hard to see in the pic. I was always taught to only prune when a plant is showing strong growth so it has energy to recover. But then, I don't know this type of bush.

Comment: If you're in the US, what zone are you in?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a sprout or two from the bottom of the shrub, which is consistent with buddleia growth in US zones 5b and 6. The tops of these plants almost always die back to the ground over winter. Try cutting one branch down to the ground, starting about two feet from the top and then working your way downward. Within each segment you cut, the interior of the branch will probably be brown and dead.

- If the branch interior is green, stop cutting that branch and work
  your way down the remaining branches.
- If the interior remains brown all the way to the bottom, cut all
  branches about 3 inches from ground level.